# Would Statement st=con.CreateStatement() be an example of composition?

Tags: java, composition

Would this be considered composition?

```
Statement st=con.CreateStatement();
```

I believe this is correct. The `con.CreateStatement()` I think is an example of Factory methods which returns an object. I guess this would be somewhat similar to a constructor. We then assign it or cast it to the `Statement` reference which gives us access to the `Statement` methods. So now our `Statement` object has functionality of the connection object and access to the `Statement` methods. Would this be considered composition?

Comment: Pay more attention in class. Both of you.

Comment: So why did they cast it up to the superclass Statement then? Connections must be be a subclass it should have access to its parents methods, so what was the point of doing this?

Comment: The point is that you're supposed to use the JDBC API, instead of depending on the actual implementation. That's what allows you to switch databases without modifying your database code (at least in theory).

Comment: Ok just to clarify, so they did this to take advantage of polymorphism, now its flexible and can connect to any data source (relational databases, spreadsheets, ect), anything that expects the statement reference. So I don't have to modify my connection code and can switch out databases?

Comment: Yeah. It's a great example of abstract factory and its advantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not composition. That's just an [Abstract Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).

Composition is discussed for example in the well known [Prefer Composition over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) "rule".